# How to individually style two ant.design components?

Tags: html, css, dropdown, antd

I'm trying to style two different `Dropdown` components from [ant.design](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/).

For one `Dropdown` component, I usually create a `css` file, find the specific `className`, edit the component using `css`, and then import the `css` file. Whenever I do this though, all of the `Dropdown` components I use throughout the webapp get modified with the same `css` file even if I don't import the `css` file into the specific file.

In this case, I want to style two `Dropdown` components differently. How can I do this?

Any help is appreciated; thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

i usually just use styled-components and then wrap the component. I use react front end tho.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

<LoginForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
</LoginForm>

const LoginForm = styled(Form)`
  max-width: 300px;
  align-self: start;
  justify-self: center;
`;
```